# Get the complexity of T(n)=T(n/4)+T(3n/4)+c

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, recurrence

In this recurrence relation `T(n)=T(n/4)+T(3n/4)+c` , I am having just confusion that what is the relation of this recurrence relation with the best and worst case analysis since we have to solve both the sub-problems which are of size n/4 and 3n/4 so what  is the terminology of worst case or best case analysis here ?

Moreover we should use here theta(log n ) our O(log n ) ,although seeing the below link I found O(log n ) more applicable but still couldn't get why are we not using theta(log n ) here .

[How to solve the recursive complexity T(n) = T(n/4)+T(3n/4)+cn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22033805/how-to-solve-the-recursive-complexity-tn-tn-4t3n-4cn)

Comment: You cannot perform best and worst case analysis based on a single recurrence relation. The recurrence relation has already the context of being best/average/worst/... case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
T(n) = T(n/4) + T(3n/4) + CONST <= 2T(3n/4) + CONST
```

We will use [case 1 of master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Case_1) with:

```
a = 2, b = 4/3.
c = log_{4/3}(2) ~= 0.4
CONST is in O(n^0.4)
```

Thus, from master theorem, one cad derive that `2T(3n/4) + CONST` is in `Theta(logn)`, and since `T(n) <= 2T(3n/4) + CONST`, we can say that `T(n)` is in `O(logn)`.

By following the same idea, but with lower bound:

```
T(n) >= T(3n/4) + CONST ...
```

And using master theorem again, we can tell that T(n) is also in `Omega(logn)`.

Since T(n) is both O(logn) and Omega(logn), it is also Theta(logn).

---

As for your question, you can use either big-O or Theta notation, whatever you prefer. As you can see, proving Theta requires a bit more work, but it is also more informative, as it tells you the bound you found is tight.

Comment: @RadhaGogia Because `T(n/4) > 0`, and thus `T(n) = T(n/4) + T(3n/4) + CONST >= T(3n/4) + CONST`

Comment: Just last confusion that seeing this recurrence relation we can easily observe that we have 2 sub-problems one of size n/4 and other of size 3n/4 so what is the relation of best  and worst case with respect to derived time complexities since in any case we have to solve both the sub-problems so then how is it affecting time complexity .

Comment: @RadhaGogia Base case/worst case/... are how you extract the function in the first place from the algorithm. Once you have your complexity function `T(n) = ...`, the analysis type (best/worst/..) is already set up.

Answer (score 1):

These types of recurrences can be easily solved with Akra-Bazzi theorem (and if you have looked at the question you linked, someone showed you a solution to a similar problem).

So `1/4^p + (3/4)^p = 1`, where `p = 1`. In your case `g(u) = c`, so the integral

[image]

So `int c/u^2 du` from `1 to x` which is equal to `-1/u` evaluated from `1 to x`. This is equal to `-1/x + 1`. Now when you multiply it by `x` and you will get that the complexity is **O(n)** and not `O(log n)` as other people suggested.